# Rubymine Array Literal Syntax (%w) Hotkey?

Tags: ruby, rubymine

I have been getting the suggestion of converting my array `['one', 'two', 'three']` to array literal syntax: `%w(one two three)`.

Does anyone know if there is a hotkey in Rubymine that will do this automatically?

Comment: You mean on a per-suggestion basis? Should be able to alt-enter and it'll pop up as a solution. If you mean across the whole project, I don't think so. You could also disable the extension if you don't care.

Comment: You're awesome, this is just what I was looking for! Do you want to convert this to a formal answer?